# What is the value of $\sqrt{49-x^2}+\sqrt{25-x^2}, x \in \mathbb{R}$ if $\sqrt{49-x^2}-\sqrt{25-x^2}=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Suppose that real number $x$ satisfies $$\sqrt{49-x^2}-\sqrt{25-x^2}=3$$What is the value of $\sqrt{49-x^2}+\sqrt{25-x^2}$?

---

This is what I did:
I try to multiply by the conjugate. Its value I believe is technically the solution. $(\sqrt {49-x^2} + \sqrt {25-x^2})(\sqrt {49-x^2} - \sqrt {25-x^2})=24$. Given that $(\sqrt {49-x^2} - \sqrt {25-x^2}) = 3$, $(\sqrt {49-x^2} + \sqrt {25-x^2})(\sqrt {49-x^2} - \sqrt {25-x^2})= 3(\sqrt {49-x^2} + \sqrt {25-x^2}) =24\implies \sqrt {49-x^2} + \sqrt {25-x^2}=8$

---

My question is that will this method work for similar problems, and is there a faster method?
Thanks!

Comment: This looks very quick to me compared with moving one square root to the other side, squaring, moving everything except the cross term to one side, squaring again, and sorting things out.  Very slick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically used the formula $$a+b=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a-b}$$ 
in an indirect way.

The problem gave you $a-b$ and, since $a,b$ are square roots of simple expressions, it is easy to calculate $a^2-b^2$.

And for the same reason, the same trick can be used to calculate 
$$\sqrt{\mbox{nice}}\pm \sqrt{\mbox{nice}}$$
whenever when $\sqrt{\mbox{nice}}\mp \sqrt{\mbox{nice}}$ is given.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:
$$1) \ \sqrt{49-x^2}=\sqrt{25-x^2}+3 \Rightarrow \\ 
49-x^2=25-x^2+9+6\sqrt{25-x^2} \Rightarrow \\
2.5=\sqrt{25-x^2};\\
2) \ \sqrt{25-x^2}=\sqrt{49-x^2}-3 \Rightarrow \\
25-x^2=49-x^2+9-6\sqrt{49-x^2} \Rightarrow \\
\sqrt{49-x^2}=5.5.$$
Hence:
$$\sqrt{49-x^2}+\sqrt{25-x^2}=5.5+2.5=8.$$

Comment: thx for this method

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying both sides by $\sqrt {49-x^2} + \sqrt {25-x^2}$, yields:

$$(\sqrt {49-x^2} + \sqrt {25-x^2})(\sqrt {49-x^2} - \sqrt {25-x^2})=3(\sqrt {49-x^2} + \sqrt {25-x^2})$$

$$(49-x^2 - (25-x^2)=3(\sqrt {49-x^2} + \sqrt {25-x^2})$$

Thus,

$$\sqrt {49-x^2} + \sqrt {25-x^2}=8.$$